# Editing property portalHostname in ArcGIS Portal?

Tags: arcgis-portal

I've inherited an ArcGIS Portal site which was set up some time ago and in which people can successfully create maps and apps and link to them but there's a problem with using the save as option when trying to make a copy of an existing map.  The saved copy is given an invalid URL which means it then can't be opened.  It looks like this is probably a problem with the original configuration of the Portal.  If I go to the ArcGIS Portal Directory page at ...*myportal*.../sharing/portals/self I can see that there is a property called portalHostname which looks like it has a typo in it which is what I'm seeing in the generated URLs.  It shows up formatted like this: /\foo.com\bar\home.  This should really be foo.com/bar as I can see it in a separate installation that works fine.

Does anybody know how this property can be changed?

I'm not seeing any way to update it even when logged in as an administrator.

Answer (score 3):

For future searches. That value can be changed at

http://portalhostname/webadaptorContext/portaladmin/system/webadptors/WebAdaptorID/edit

You will have to type in the /edit, then change the Web Adaptor Machine URL to the DNS alias or whatever you want to use. It will restart the portal immediately so do this during down time.